# Plot confidence interval around curve

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I need to plot a confidence band around a curve in Mathematica, similarly to what done with `r` in the image below (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358811/extract-prediction-band-from-lme-fit)).

[image]

What is the best way to do it? My code is simply

```
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}];
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, Pi/3}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 LabelStyle -> Opacity[0]]
```

and the resulting curve is also shown below.

[image]

Comment: How is your interval defined? By an offset? Please elaborate.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of my resource function [BayesianLinearRegression](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BayesianLinearRegression). It has a number of these types of plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In V.12 this functionality has been finally automated with `Around` and `IntervalMarkers`.
The code is as simple as that (@JimB's correct band procedure can be incorporated as well).

```
list = Table[Around[Sin[2 x], 0.2], {x, 0, Pi/3, Pi/3/20}];

ListLinePlot[list, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[list, IntervalMarkers -> "Bars", PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Your figure with the "band" shows a 95% prediction band and not a 95% confidence band.  In *Mathematica* lingo you need to decide on whether you want a `SinglePredictionBand` or a `MeanPredictionBand`, respectively.  (And the one you show is not appropriate given the change in variance from low predictor values to high predictor values.)

Here is an example for obtaining both types of bands:

```
n = 100;
x = Table[(π/3) i/n, {i, n}];
y = Sin[2 x] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], n];
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + Sin[b t], {{a, 0}, {b, 2}}, t];
Show[ListPlot[data],
 Plot[{nlm[t], nlm["SinglePredictionBands"], 
   nlm["MeanPredictionBands"]}, {t, 0, π/3}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {1}}], Frame -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -0.5}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Confidence and prediction bands]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this,

```
confidenceinterval = .2;
Plot[{Sin[2 x],
  Sin[2 x] + .5 confidenceinterval,
  Sin[2 x] - .5 confidenceinterval},
 {x, 0, Pi/3},
 Filling -> {3 -> {2}},
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], Pink],
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, @JasonB.  I have no *confidence* in this answer.  If there's data involved, the width of the band won't be constant.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Your sermons are appreciated, I pretend no knowledge of statistics, I just viewed the question as "how can I make this pretty plot with a pink stripe and blue line down the middle?"

Comment: I figured as much.  But I just couldn't resist the opportunity.