# Mapping over function's several parameters regions

Tags: plotting, evaluation, syntax, map

About this post:

[Mapping multiple parameters of a function to specific values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/mapping-multiple-parameters-of-a-function-to-specific-values)

I wonder if the parameters `a` and `b` have ranges with steps, as: a-> {1,5,0.5}, which means a =1,1.5,2,...,5.

How the definition of the parameters will be written then instead being with fixed values as in the referred post

`parameters = {{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1/3}, {2, 1/4}, {0.5, 1/5}};`  ?

Comment: Yeah, realized that, deleted comment...

Comment: Please make this question self contained. Prepare minimal example and tell us what exactly do you want to get. Do you want to plot all possible combinations of generated parameters or maybe respective pairs, etc etc.

Comment: @Kuba. I just will repeat the previous question in the post I referred to ! put as I said in the question I want the parameters go to ranges not for specific values

Comment: @S.S. What haven't you got from my comment? I understand you want ranges.

Comment: @ Kuba. Fine !!

Comment: @S.S. fine what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Mapping multiple parameters of a function to specific values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/mapping-multiple-parameters-of-a-function-to-specific-values) and supply it with the following version of `parameters`.

```
parameters=Flatten[Table[{a, 1/bInverted}, {a, 1/2, 5, 1/2}, {bInverted, 2, 5}], 1]
```

### Update

Let's redefine `myfunction` to be a function of `a`, `b` and `x`.

```
myfunction[a_, b_, x_] := (b/a)*((a/x)^(b + 1))
```

Now when you generate `parameters`

```
parameters = Flatten[
   Table[{a, 1/bInverted}, {a, 1/2, 5, 1/2}, {bInverted, 2, 5}], 1]
```

and plot it

```
Plot[myfunction[Sequence @@ #, x] & /@ parameters, {x, 0, 3},
 Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

you get several lines.

You ask

*But is there a way in this case to plot `myfunction` in a single line instead versus `x` for continuous regions for `a` and `b` ?*

Certainly it can't be done as a single line, but you could plot a band between the lowest and highest values similar to [Plot confidence interval around curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114198/plot-confidence-interval-around-curve).

A test shows that the lowest values are achieved with the minimum for `a` and `b` and the largest values for the maximum. So we plot two curves and area shade between them.

```
Plot[{myfunction[1/2, 1/5, x], myfunction[5, 1/2, x]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], Gray], 
 PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I know that names are arbitrary but `x` is not a parameter in linked question so it may be confusing here. Also, there is a pair of values and it's not clear if OP wants pair of ranges or multiple pairs.

Comment: @Kuba I couldn't figure how to get an interator of the form `{b, 1/2, 1/5}` so thought it would be better to use `x`. I will change it to `bInverted`.

Comment: @ Jack LaVigne. Ok I used: `parameters=Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, 1/2, 5, 1/2}, {b, 2, 5,1/2}], 1]` , because `a` and `b` are the independent parameters and `x` is the variable i want to plot myfunction versus it as in the previous example. I got a several lines for myfunction according to the {a,b} generated pairs. But is there a way in this case to plot `myfunction` in a single line instead versus `x` for continuous regions for `a` and `b` ?.

Comment: Herply thanks @Jack LaVigne for your effort, I will try it..

Comment: Hay @Kuba, thanks for your trail to understand my question ..