# Correct filling for confidence interval

Tags: plotting, filling

I have the following list:

```
data1={{2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78,
   2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 
  2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 
  2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.56, 2.78, 2.4}, {2.55, 2.77, 
  2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 
  2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 
  2.39}, {2.55, 2.77, 2.39}, {2.54, 2.76, 2.38}, {2.54, 2.76, 
  2.38}, {2.54, 2.76, 2.38}, {2.53, 2.75, 2.37}, {2.53, 2.75, 
  2.37}, {2.52, 2.74, 2.36}, {2.51, 2.73, 2.35}, {2.49, 2.72, 
  2.34}, {2.48, 2.7, 2.33}, {2.46, 2.68, 2.31}, {2.44, 2.66, 
  2.28}, {2.41, 2.63, 2.26}, {2.38, 2.59, 2.23}, {2.34, 2.55, 
  2.19}, {2.29, 2.5, 2.15}, {2.24, 2.44, 2.09}, {0.45, 0.52, 
  0.39}, {0.45, 0.52, 0.39}, {0.45, 0.51, 0.38}, {0.44, 0.51, 
  0.38}, {0.44, 0.5, 0.38}, {0.44, 0.5, 0.37}, {0.44, 0.5, 
  0.37}, {0.44, 0.5, 0.38}, {0.44, 0.5, 0.38}, {0.44, 0.5, 
  0.38}, {0.44, 0.49, 0.38}, {0.44, 0.49, 0.38}, {0.44, 0.49, 0.38},
  {0.44, 0.49, 0.38}, {0.54, 0.63, 0.47}, {0.54, 0.63, 0.47}, {0.54, 
  0.63, 0.47}, {0.54, 0.63, 0.47}, {0.54, 0.63, 0.47}, {0.54, 0.63, 
  0.47}, {0.54, 0.63, 0.47}, {0.69, 0.81, 0.61}, {0.69, 0.81, 
  0.61}, {0.69, 0.81, 0.61}, {0.69, 0.81, 0.61}, {0.69, 0.81, 
  0.61}, {0.69, 0.81, 0.61}, {0.69, 0.81, 0.61}, {0.85, 1, 
  0.73}, {0.84, 1, 0.72}, {0.84, 1, 0.72}, {0.84, 0.99, 0.72}, {0.84, 
  0.99, 0.72}, {0.84, 0.99, 0.72}, {0.84, 0.99, 0.72}, {0.87, 1.04, 
  0.74}, {0.87, 1.04, 0.74}, {0.87, 1.04, 0.74}, {0.87, 1.04, 
  0.74}, {0.87, 1.04, 0.74}, {0.87, 1.04, 0.74}, {0.87, 1.04, 
  0.74}, {0.88, 1.05, 0.72}, {0.87, 1.05, 0.72}, {0.87, 1.05, 
  0.72}, {0.87, 1.05, 0.72}, {0.87, 1.05, 0.72}, {0.87, 1.05, 
  0.72}, {0.87, 1.05, 0.72}, {0.91, 1.15, 0.68}, {0.91, 1.15, 
  0.68}, {0.91, 1.15, 0.68}, {0.91, 1.15, 0.68}, {0.91, 1.15, 
  0.68}, {0.91, 1.15, 0.68}, {0.91, 1.15, 0.68}, {0.95, 1.2, 
  0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 
  0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 
  0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 
  0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 
  0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}, {0.95, 1.2, 0.72}}
```

where the second and third entries are condifence intervals. I plot them as:

```
plt1 = ListLinePlot[data1[[All, 1]], PlotStyle -> Black, 
   Frame -> True];
plt2 = ListLinePlot[data1[[All, 2]], PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Frame -> True];
plt3 = ListLinePlot[data1[[All, 3]], PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Frame -> True];
Show[plt1, plt2, plt3, PlotRange -> All]
```

I wonder how to do the filling only between confident intervals, I tried `filling->Bottom` or top but it fills the place I do not desire. I looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114198/plot-confidence-interval-around-curve) but I can not grasp the meaning of `Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {1}}]`

Comment: The general way for drawing confidence intervals is using `Around`. The syntax of this is available in the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[data1], 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Red], Directive[Red]},
 Filling -> {2 -> {3}}, FillingStyle -> {Opacity[.25], Pink}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: filling confidence intervals plot]

Comment: This is very neat especially the `Transpose` part, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have version 12.+, you can also use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) to process `data1` and use `ListLinePlot` with the options [`IntervalMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkers.html) and [`IntervalMarkersStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkersStyle.html):

```
data1b = Around[#, {#3, #2} - #] & @@@ data1;

ListLinePlot[data1b, 
 IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> Pink, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, Scaled[.1]}}]
```

[image]